# SpringBootBackendApplication.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When trying to run SpringBoot application, I get the following errors:

```
SpringBootBackendApplication.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
                              ^
SpringBootBackendApplication.java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
                                           ^
SpringBootBackendApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
```

This also happened with another project of mine. Does the project have to be run with Maven? If not, what could be causing an error such as this? Is the code even supposed to be executable in its current state?

My Pom File:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ourlibrary</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-backend</name>
    <description>Our Library </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.ourlibrary.springboot.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Main Method:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class SpringBootBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: seems your code doesn't find spring library, make sure you have library in your local maven repository or in your code classpath, then do mvn clean compile or you can create project from https://start.spring.io

Comment: Did you rebuild your project? I think that is the reason.

Comment: how are you running your application `mvn spring-boot:run` ?

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt my project. Whenever I try and run the main method, I get this error: Application.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist